# Выборка данных из бд MongoDB

Tags: база-данных, node.js, mongodb

Я использую mongodb-driver для работы с бд. Мне нужно получить только те поля которые мне нужны. В SQL я сделал бы такой запрос:

```sql
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE 1
```

Я попробовал такой код:

```js
collection.find({}, {_id: 0, column1: 1 }).toArray((err, results) => {
  return results;
});
```

Но он возвращает все поля, в том числе _id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было так:

```js
collection.find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, column1: 1 } }, (err, results) => {
   //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Эльдар, 
тебе не хватает условия в запросе после WHERE. 
К примеру:

SELECT maker FROM product WHERE **type = 'printer'**;

Comment: Вопрос про список возвращаемых колонок, при чём тут фильтрация в `WHERE`?